# Integrate Stripe 3D secure payments with Ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

I'm trying to make 3D secure stripe payments on my Ionic APP, It's easier to do it on web with iframe but the native stripe plugin on Ionic platform doesn't let us to create a source that is required for 3D card payment.

I can make payment without 3D secure but with 3D secure I have to figure out the best way to open 3D secure authentication page. That launches on popup/iframe on web.

```
import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe/ngx';

constructor(private stripe: Stripe) { }

...

this.stripe.setPublishableKey('my_publishable_key');

let card = {
 number: '4242424242424242',
 expMonth: 12,
 expYear: 2020,
 cvc: '220'
}

this.stripe.createCardToken(card)
   .then(token => console.log(token.id))
   .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

But can't use 3D secure with ionic-native/stripe/ is there is a way out?

Comment: how you implementing in ionic4 so far? put code snapshot

Comment: Done @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: I order to do this, you'll need to use [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents). You'll want to contact Ionic's developers to see if/when they intend to support those.